# The generic form of instanton (antiinstanton) in Kahler $\sigma$-model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory, topology, instantons

Suppose we have some compact Riemann surface $\Sigma$ , and scalar field $\phi$, which takes values in some Kahler manifold (target space) $M$. In other words, we have a map:
$$
\phi : \Sigma \rightarrow M.
$$ 
The action with topological term, as far I as understand, would have the following form:
$$
\int d^2 x \sqrt{g} \ G_{I J} \partial_\mu \phi^{I} \partial^\mu \phi^{J} \pm 
\int d^2 x \ \varepsilon^{\mu \nu} \ J_{I J} \partial_\mu \phi^{I} \partial_\nu \phi^{J} 
$$
Where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is a metric on $\Sigma$, $G_{I J}$ is metric on a target space, $J_{I J}$ is the complex structure on $M$. Employing something similar to BPS trick we write the following inequality:
$$
\int d^2 x \sqrt{g} \ G_{I J}(\partial_\mu \phi^{I} \pm \varepsilon_{\mu \nu} J_{K}^{I} \partial^{\nu}\phi^{K})
(\partial^\mu \phi^{J} \pm \varepsilon^{\mu \nu} J_{K}^{I} \partial_{\nu}\phi^{K}) \geq 0.
$$
So the bound seems to be saturated on the fields, satisfying following equations:
$$
\partial_\mu \phi^{I} \pm \varepsilon_{\mu \nu} J_{K}^{I} \partial^{\nu}\phi^{K} = 0.
$$
*Is it the correct expression*, and are all these equations independent? Naively, I see $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} \Sigma \times \dim_{\mathbb{R}} M$. However, the complex structure $J$ is not arbitrary, but satisfies $J^2 = -1$. Thus there should be less equations. *Is there a way to make this more manifest?*